# LSTM for time series forecasting with H20.ai

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, rnn, lstm

I want to implement a time-series prediction model using LSTMs like the one mentioned here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

The model works pretty well using a similar Keras code above, though I want to implement the same using H20.ai

This [documentation here on H2O Deep Water](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html) says "The H2O Deep Water project supports CNNs and **RNNs** though third-party integrations of other deep learning libraries such as TensorFlow, Caffe and MXNet.". Though there are no demos for the same.

In this conversation here in Jan '16 on ['Recurrent Neural Networks in H2O for time series prediction?'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/qU2FezMCyW8), they say it hasn't been implemented yet.

Any advice or links to similar implementations on H2O would be deeply appreciated

Note: I am looking for a data parallel architecture implementation rather than model parallelism

Answer (score 2):

Active development on H2O's Deep Water project has stopped, see here: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater

I don't think LSTM was included in the last release, and I would use Keras instead.

A list of Jupyter notebook demos is found here as well: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/examples/deeplearning/notebooks